# Pinia reading getter from another getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have a store in Pinia (using Vue 3), that often uses getters that reference other getters. I've been using `state.getterName` to reference, and it's been working but sometimes warns me the getter does not exist. I somehow missed in the [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html) that I should be using `this.` when referencing a getter within another getter.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', {
    state:() =>({
        state1: 100
    }),
    getters: {
        getterName1: (state) => {
           return state.state1 * 100
        },
        getterName2: (state) => {
           return state.getterName1 - 100
        }
    }
})
```

I think I should be doing this:

```
const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', {
    state:() =>({
        state1: 100
    }),
    getters: {
        getterName1: (state) => {
           return state.state1 * 100
        },
        getterName2: () => {
           return this.getterName1 - 100
        }
    }
})
```

My question is: why does incorrectly using `state.getterName` work? What risks do I add by not using `this`? Should I refactor my store to use `this`?

Adding in [this discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1076) in case it adds context. Also wanted to mention I'm not using TypeScript, so I can't force the return type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable

Comment: You're misusing an arrow, you won't find it be used together with `this` if you follow the guides. I'm quite sure that you're limited to using the state and not getters when you use state.getterName, at least with TS

Comment: Any idea why it's letting me use getters when I use `state`? I'm not using TS.

Comment: Likely because `state` is the whole store in this case, but since it's not documented, it's not a good thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you an alternative, Vue 3 works much better with Composition APi, faster, more intuitive and easier to understand, this is how I handle it and it does not cause conflicts and little by little your application is scaling

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue

export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore',() => {
const state1 = ref(100);

const getterName1 = () => state1.value * 100
const getterName2 = () => state1.value - 100

return {state1,getterName1, getterName2}
})
```

and now you can use it in any component like this

```
import {useMyStore} from 'yourpath/'
const useStore = useMyStore

const test = () => {
useStore.getterName1()
}

<template>
<p>{{useStore.state1}}</p>
</template>
```

hope helpfull

Comment: This would work but would actually mean that the function is now an `action` instead of a `getter`. To have it be a `getter`, you should make it `computed`